# jQuery table paging

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

I have a usual html table and want to add ajax-paging to it (table data should be reloaded). I'm sure there should be some jQuery plugin for that :)

Answer (score 6):

**[Yes, you can go for JQuery pagination plugin for that.](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/pagination/)**

Answer (score 1):

In case you are interested in extending the basic HTML table's display, you can go for jquery grid plugin

the js files are available @ http://datatables.net/

This plugin provides paging, themerollers, export toolbar, sorting and filtering